# Solr 1.4 Date Facet Include

Tags: solr, faceted-search

My goal is to get a document count for each month over the past year. Here is the faceted query I am using against Solr 1.4:

```
q=*:*
rows=0
facet=on
facet.date=myDateField
facet.date.start=NOW-11MONTH/MONTH
facet.date.end=NOW+1MONTH/MONTH
facet.date.gap=+1MONTH
```

The ranges this query produces are `2013-01-01T00:00:00Z to 2013-02-01T00:00:00Z`, which is inclusive for the upper bound, meaning `T00:00:00Z` on the first of every month is being counted in 2 different ranges.

[Solr 3.1 introduces](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.date.include) the `facet.date.include` parameter that would solve my problem, except upgrading right now is not an option. Is there a workaround to achieving the same functionality? I tried `facet.date.gap=+1MONTH-1SECOND` which is close, but not close enough. It produces something like this where the end date is not correct:

```
2012-09-01T00:00:00Z
2012-09-30T23:59:59Z
2012-10-30T23:59:58Z
2012-11-30T23:59:57Z
2012-12-30T23:59:56Z
2013-01-30T23:59:55Z
2013-02-28T23:59:54Z
2013-03-28T23:59:53Z
2013-04-28T23:59:52Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking can be done with facet queries instead of facet range.
Try something like this:

```
facet.query=myDateField:[NOW-11MONTH/MONTH TO NOW-10MONTH/MONTH] 
facet.query=myDateField:[NOW-10MONTH/MONTH TO NOW-9MONTH/MONTH] 
facet.query=myDateField:[NOW-9MONTH/MONTH TO NOW-8MONTH/MONTH] ...
```

and so on.

Now you have ful control over any single facet, so you can do -1DAY in the last facet if you need to.
Have a look at the reference for date math syntax:
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/DateMathParser.html

Comment: that still creates a range with an upper bound of the first day of the next month, inclusively. output is the same as my original date facet example

Comment: you have to work on the last facet. in this way you have full control over it. try to put -1day in the last facet like this: NOW+1MONTH-1DAY/MONTH

Comment: ah ok, I see now. I will accept your answer because it looks like it should work, but we opted to take a different route. We temporarily modified our data to add 1 second to midnight of the first of every month (ie 2013-08-01T00:00:01Z) to force it outside of the facet range. I know it's a pretty big hack, but it will serve our purpose until we can upgrade Solr.